Postgresql I want to change my id , because is negative and i want positive number
i create a postgresql schema with table . In my table player i have id positive but in my table referee i have id negative. I don't understand why  are ids different , i use the same proprieties.
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS i_match.td_player
    ADD COLUMN id_player bigint NOT NULL;

the same for my table referee and this is the definition of my table referee => -- Table: i_match.td_referee
-- DROP TABLE IF EXISTS i_match.td_referee;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS i_match.td_referee
(
    last_name character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    first_name character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    id_referee bigint NOT NULL,
    birth_date date,
    CONSTRAINT "PK_TD_REFEREE" PRIMARY KEY (id_referee)
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS i_match.td_referee
    OWNER to elodie_nebulot;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS i_match.td_referee
    ALTER COLUMN id_referee SET STATISTICS 1;

my row player 1 => id = 1 name => john datebegin = 23/09/2023
my row referee 1=> id = -1 ....... i want a positive number not a negative number

Just update the record. And check the code that created this negative number, that's the real problem. Offtopic: Why did you change the statistics? That's rather unusual, especially the value 1.

hello, thanks you for your answer but i haven't modify my structure. Td_player and td_referee are the same structure. I didn't want change the statistics. I just want to have for the two table, an id value = positive. But in the td_player the id is positive, not in the td_referee. Finally i find the answer => I select td_referee and in the query tool => i create sequence with the min number (for ex CREATE SEQUENCE i_match.referee_id_seq START 1000; ) and after join my seq to my id_referee (UPDATE i_match.td_referee
SET id_referee = nextval('i_match.referee_id_seq')
WHERE id_referee < 0;)
